# setting up typescript with webpack

Tags: typescript, express, webpack, ts-loader

I am using Typescript to develop a back-end API with graphql and express. I am using webpack to manage the project development and building process.

I am using raw-loader to load graphql schemas and sql queries from files as strings.

Currently I am facing some issues that I don't really understand.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: {
    server: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.ts'),
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(gql|sql)$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  watch: {
    ignored: /node_modues/,
  },
};
```

server.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';

import { affairSchema } from './src/schemas';
import affairRoot from './src/resolvers/affairs';

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: affairSchema,
    rootValue: affairRoot,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server waiting on ', port));
```

errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs
88:0-148:42 Can't reexport the named export 'typeFromAST' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs
 @ ./src/schemas/index.ts
 @ ./server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs
88:0-148:42 Can't reexport the named export 'valueFromAST' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs
 @ ./src/schemas/index.ts
 @ ./server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs
88:0-148:42 Can't reexport the named export 'valueFromASTUntyped' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs
 @ ./src/schemas/index.ts
 @ ./server.ts

ERROR in C:\Users\houssem\Projects\ctc\services\affairs\src\schemas\index.ts
./src/schemas/index.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\houssem\Projects\ctc\services\affairs\src\schemas\index.ts(5,28)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './affairs.gql'.

ERROR in C:\Users\houssem\Projects\ctc\services\affairs\services\database\engineer.ts
./services/database/engineer.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\houssem\Projects\ctc\services\affairs\services\database\engineer.ts(7,19)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './engineer.sql'.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Maybe use externals via [`webpack-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals)?

Comment: @H.B. worked, thank you a lot.

Comment: OK, i guess that could count as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`webpack-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) to prevent bundling of the node modules. This can get rid of such errors, but of course also requires `node_modules` when running the application.

Comment: So I need to deploy the node_modules file also to get my server running.

Comment: That should be the case, yes.